# Moving std::clog in source to output file

Tags: c++, file, debugging, logging, output

I have a basic debug message in my code that prints a message as to what function is called.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
     std::clog << "message etc" << std::endl;
#endif
```

How do I redirect the output to send the message to a textfile?

Comment: You can't, not without also redirecting normal output (if you use redirection from outside of the program). The onbly way is to use another output stream, possibly a reference that you initialize either to the output file stream or `std::clog`.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the buffer associated with `clog` that uses a file to save its data to.

Here's a simple program that demonstrates the concept.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
   std::ofstream out("test.txt");

   // Get the rdbuf of clog.
   // We need it to reset the value before exiting.
   auto old_rdbuf = std::clog.rdbuf();

   // Set the rdbuf of clog.
   std::clog.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());

   // Write to clog.
   // The output should go to test.txt.
   std::clog << "Test, Test, Test.\n";

   // Reset the rdbuf of clog.
   std::clog.rdbuf(old_rdbuf);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: More generally with example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdbuf/

Comment: What happens if one doesn't reset `std::clog` before exiting? Would that affect the system in any way?

Comment: @thomthom, if anything is written to `std::clog` during the termination phase of the program, the program will run into undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I redirect the output to send the message to a textfile?

As far *redirect* means from outside the program code, it depends a bit on your shell syntax actually. According [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/clog) `std::clog` is usually bound to `std::cerr`:

> > The global objects `std::clog` and `std::wclog` control output to a stream buffer of implementation-defined type (derived from `std::streambuf`), associated with the standard C output stream stderr, but, unlike `std::cerr/std::wcerr`, these streams are not automatically flushed and not automatically tie()'d with cout.

So e.g. in bash you would do something like

```
$ program 2> Logs.txt
```

---

Regarding *redirecting* programmatically, you can do it as mentioned in [R Sahu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34619037/1413395), or explained in the [currently marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357/what-is-the-point-of-clog).